# inside mechanism of geospatial indexing in mongodb

Tags: sql, algorithm, mongodb, geospatial

Anyone knows how the geospatial indexing works, i mean the algorithm to calculate nearest points?

In SQL we may do things like this:
`SELECT id, (x-a)*(x-a)+(y-b)*(y-b) as distance FROM table1 ORDER by distance ASC`
Sure this is not efficient enough compared with mongodb's geospatial indexing, but how does mongodb calculate and sort?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heart of mongodb geospatial is [Geohashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). Geohash is a

> Hierarchical spatial data structure which subdivides space into
>   buckets of grid shape.

I couldn't find the appropriate links for the geohash implementations in mongo, but this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/c59e1763c9667bb8) might give some insights.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. Never heard of Geohashes, seems i need to google and delve into that first~~

Answer (score 3):

from the [10gen site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing):

> The current implementation encodes geographic hash codes atop standard
>   MongoDB B-trees. Results of $near queries are exact. One limitation
>   with this encoding, while fast, is that prefix lookups don't give
>   exact results, especially around bit flip areas.  MongoDB solves this
>   by doing a grid-neighbor search after the initial prefix scan to pick
>   up any straggler points.  This generally ensures that performance
>   remains very high while providing correct results.

Comment: There are also comments on the specifics of the implementation in the C++ source code which is open source and available for download (I have the source code on another computer but I think it's a z-order-b-tree ... from my understanding the end result is basically a quad key algorithm)